# Existence of subdivision of PL manifold triangulation which is combinatorial manifold

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, triangulation

Suppose $X$ is a PL manifold with triangulation $\psi:|\Delta| \to X$. Does there exist a subdivision of $\psi$ which is a combinatorial triangulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $\psi$ is not combinatorial, no, never, because subdivision preserves the homeomorphism type of the link of a vertex. (In particular, if it's not a sphere, you're out of luck.) This is reasonably straightforward to prove.

Comment: I don't really understand the context of the question, but I am intrigued - everything sounds familiar except for the word "combinatorial". Do you really mean "never"? I.e., do the definitions involved here somehow exclude familiar examples like circles and spheres and tori with standard triangulations?

Comment: @RobArthan The word combinatorial is the crucial word. A combinatorial triangulation is one such that the link of every vertex is a sphere. For a polyhedron/simplicial complex, this is the same as saying that you're locally PL homeomorphic with $\Bbb R^n$. (I've edited my answer to include the implicit assumption that the triangulation is not combinatorial.) Now, non-combinatorial triangulations exist. I think the first well-known one comes from the following construction. Let $M$ be a homology sphere that's not $S^n$. The most famous example of such is probably Poincare's homology sphere.

Comment: Then the double suspension theorem says that $\Sigma \Sigma M$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n+2}$. Now triangulate $M$. The suspensions naturally have triangulations, so and the link of the "cone vertices" in $\Sigma \Sigma M$ is homeomorphic to $\Sigma M$ - which is not a manifold, and in particular not a sphere. So the first place we get a noncombiatorial triangulation is $S^5$. I do believe it's possible to find non-combinatorial triangulations in dimension 4, but I do not remember a construction. Any triangulation in dimension at most 3 is automatically combinatorial.

Comment: thanks for the very helpful explanation.